# How to search by variable in awk

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I'm trying to get the N-th row after a given pattern with awk.
The problem is that awk searches pattern literally:

```
awk -v patt=${1} -v rows=${2}'NR==p {print} /patt/ {p=NR+rows}'
```

How to escape the "patt" valiable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've maneged to get it work,with double quotes

```
patt=${1}
awk -v rows=${2} "NR==p {print} /${patt}/ {p=NR+rows}" $3
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the awk matching operator instead of the slashes:

```
awk -v patt=${1} -v rows=${2} 'NR==p {print} $0 ~ patt {p=NR+rows}'
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about the string containing the awk program, so you can build it as usual in the shell, e.g.:

```
awk -v rows=${2}'NR==p {print} /'"$1"'/ {p=NR+rows}'
```