# Trying to pass a paramater from a shell script to awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to pass a parameter to this script named HandleError.sh:

```
#!/bin/ksh
s=$1
echo $s
awk -v search=$s '$0 ~ /search/ { vart = NR }{ arr[NR]=$0 } END { for (i = vart; 
i<=NR ;  i++)     
print arr[i]  }' W_ERP_CLINICAL_LOAD.out > ENCOUNTER_DETAIL_ERROR.txt
```

I am calling it like this:

```
HandleError.sh BEGIN EMR_LAB_FAC
```

I am trying to copy the file `W_ERP_CLINICAL_LOAD.out` from the first occurrence of `BEGIN EMR_LAB_FAC` to the bottom of the file.  Everything is working well except passing the parameter.

I can hard code like this and it works fine.

```
awk '$0 ~ /BEGIN ENCOUNTER_DETAIL/ { vart = NR }{ arr[NR]=$0 } END { for (i = vart; i<=NR ;  
i++) print arr[i]  }' W_ERP_CLINICAL_LOAD.out > ENCOUNTER_DETAIL_ERROR.txt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
awk -v search="$s" '$0 ~ search {f=1} f' W_ERP_CLINICAL_LOAD.out
```

no need for an array. Also the approach you had would copy the entire contents of the file if the search pattern was not found.

Comment:  This is a much better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7822337/78845)...

Replace `$0 ~ /search/` with `$0 ~ search`.